# Custom Scroll Viewer horizontal bar is in a vertical orientation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scroll, scrollview

I have a custom `scrollViewer` and the horizontal scroller is showing in a vertical orientation

[image]

Here is the code for the Horizontal ScrollBarLine:

```
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="HorizontalScrollBar" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="0" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.00001*" />
                <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="0" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border
                Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                Background="#F0F0F0"
                CornerRadius="2" />
            <RepeatButton
                Grid.Column="0"
                Width="18"
                Command="ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand"
                Content="M 4 0 L 4 8 L 0 4 Z"
                Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}" />
            <Track
                Name="PART_Track"
                Grid.Column="1"
                IsDirectionReversed="False">
                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Command="ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" />
                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <Track.Thumb>
                    <Thumb
                        Margin="0,1,0,1"
                        Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush}"
                        BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}"
                        Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}" />
                </Track.Thumb>
                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Command="ScrollBar.PageRightCommand" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" />
                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
            </Track>
            <RepeatButton
                Grid.Column="3"
                Width="18"
                Command="ScrollBar.LineRightCommand"
                Content="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 0 8 Z"
                Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}" />
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Here is the full code for the custom `ScrollViewer`

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="StandardBorderBrush" Color="#888" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="StandardBackgroundBrush" Color="LightGray" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HoverBorderBrush" Color="#DDD" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedBackgroundBrush" Color="LightGray" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedForegroundBrush" Color="White" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledForegroundBrush" Color="#888" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GlyphBrush" Color="#444" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NormalBrush" Color="#888" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NormalBorderBrush" Color="#888" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HorizontalNormalBrush" Color="#FF686868" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HorizontalNormalBorderBrush" Color="#888" />

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ListBoxBackgroundBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0.001">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="White" />
                <GradientStop Offset="0.6" Color="White" />
                <GradientStop Offset="1.2" Color="#DDDDDD" />
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="StandardBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="#FFF" />
                <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#CCC" />
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PressedBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="#BBB" />
                <GradientStop Offset="0.1" Color="#EEE" />
                <GradientStop Offset="0.9" Color="#EEE" />
                <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#FFF" />
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarLineButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Border
                        Name="Border"
                        Margin="1"
                        Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush}"
                        BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        CornerRadius="2">
                        <Path
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Data="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                            Fill="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PressedBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarPageButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Border Background="Black" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumb" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Border
                        Width="3"
                        Margin="8,0,-2,0"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        CornerRadius="2" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalScrollBar" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition MaxHeight="0" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*" />
                <RowDefinition MaxHeight="0" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border
                Grid.RowSpan="3"
                Background="Transparent"
                CornerRadius="2" />
            <RepeatButton
                Grid.Row="0"
                Height="18"
                Command="ScrollBar.LineUpCommand"
                Content="M 0 4 L 8 4 L 4 0 Z"
                Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}" />
            <Track
                Name="PART_Track"
                Grid.Row="1"
                IsDirectionReversed="true">
                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" />
                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <Track.Thumb>
                    <Thumb
                        Margin="1,0,1,0"
                        Background="{StaticResource HorizontalNormalBrush}"
                        BorderBrush="{StaticResource HorizontalNormalBorderBrush}"
                        Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}" />
                </Track.Thumb>
                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" />
                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
            </Track>
            <RepeatButton
                Grid.Row="3"
                Height="18"
                Command="ScrollBar.LineDownCommand"
                Content="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"
                Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}" />
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="HorizontalScrollBar" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="0" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.00001*" />
                <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="0" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border
                Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                Background="#F0F0F0"
                CornerRadius="2" />
            <RepeatButton
                Grid.Column="0"
                Width="18"
                Command="ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand"
                Content="M 4 0 L 4 8 L 0 4 Z"
                Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}" />
            <Track
                Name="PART_Track"
                Grid.Column="1"
                IsDirectionReversed="False">
                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Command="ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" />
                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <Track.Thumb>
                    <Thumb
                        Margin="0,1,0,1"
                        Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush}"
                        BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}"
                        Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}" />
                </Track.Thumb>
                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Command="ScrollBar.PageRightCommand" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" />
                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
            </Track>
            <RepeatButton
                Grid.Column="3"
                Width="18"
                Command="ScrollBar.LineRightCommand"
                Content="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 0 8 Z"
                Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}" />
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="18" />
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollBar}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="18" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBar}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="FavsScrollViewer" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" />
                        <ScrollBar
                            Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                            Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                            ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                            Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                            Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}" />
                        <ScrollBar
                            Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                            Orientation="Horizontal"
                            ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                            Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                            Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: isn't your line very long horizontally ?

Comment: Yes, I would like it to flipped. It’s hard to grab in that orientation

Comment: You should be able to simply set the `Height` property to something larger ([MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-customize-the-thumb-size-on-a-scrollbar))

Comment: @Cfun No, it's not. I know you're not able to tell from the image but there isn't much scrolling left to get to the end of the page. The scroll bar should be much long horizontally.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to only include the XAML needed to recreate the bottom `ScrollBar`? I'm having a very hard time reading such a long segment of code in such a small window

Comment: @MindSwipe I made the edits to include the horizontal scroll bar section of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a separate style for each `Thumb` horizontal and vertical accordingly:

```
       <Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumb" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false" />

            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Name" Value="ThumbH">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                                <Border
                        Height="5"
                        Margin="8,0,-2,0"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        CornerRadius="2" />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>

                <Trigger Property="Name" Value="ThumbV">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                                <Border
                        Width="3"
                        Margin="8,0,-2,0"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        CornerRadius="2" />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

And since I have used the property `Name` as a style triggering condition it should be set accordingly:

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalScrollBar" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition MaxHeight="0" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*" />
                <RowDefinition MaxHeight="0" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border
                Grid.RowSpan="3"
                Background="Transparent"
                CornerRadius="2" />
            <RepeatButton
                Grid.Row="0"
                Height="18"
                Command="ScrollBar.LineUpCommand"
                Content="M 0 4 L 8 4 L 4 0 Z"
                Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}" />
            <Track
                Name="PART_Track"
                Grid.Row="1"
                IsDirectionReversed="true">
                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" />
                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <Track.Thumb>
                    <!--Here Added x:Name-->
                    <Thumb
                        x:Name="ThumbV"
                        Margin="1,0,1,0"
                        Background="{StaticResource HorizontalNormalBrush}"
                        BorderBrush="{StaticResource HorizontalNormalBorderBrush}"
                        Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}" />
                </Track.Thumb>
                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" />
                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
            </Track>
            <RepeatButton
                Grid.Row="3"
                Height="18"
                Command="ScrollBar.LineDownCommand"
                Content="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"
                Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}" />
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="HorizontalScrollBar" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="0" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.00001*" />
                <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="0" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border
                Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                Background="#F0F0F0"
                CornerRadius="2" />
            <RepeatButton
                Grid.Column="0"
                Width="18"
                Command="ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand"
                Content="M 4 0 L 4 8 L 0 4 Z"
                Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}" />
            <Track
                Name="PART_Track"
                Grid.Column="1"
                IsDirectionReversed="False">
                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Command="ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" />
                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <Track.Thumb>
                    <!--Here Added x:Name-->
                    <Thumb
                        x:Name="ThumbH"
                        Margin="0,1,0,1"
                        Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush}"
                        BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}"
                        Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}" />
                </Track.Thumb>
                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Command="ScrollBar.PageRightCommand" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" />
                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
            </Track>
            <RepeatButton
                Grid.Column="3"
                Width="18"
                Command="ScrollBar.LineRightCommand"
                Content="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 0 8 Z"
                Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}" />
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Note: You can change the `Height` property of the horizontal thumb and the `Width` property of the vertical one to fit your needs.